# How to move WebComponent to folder and use it then?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am trying to make pretty simple things work for me in Dart. I created web-ui application from template and want to move xclick-counter web component out from root folder.
Here how my project looks like in the Dart Editor:

```
NewComposite (folder)
   pubspec.lock (file)
   pubspec.yaml (file)
   web (folder)
      lib(folder)
         comp1.dart (file)
         Comp1.html (file)
         mylib.dart (file)
      newcomposite.css (file)
      newcomposite.dart (file)
      newcomposite.html (file)
      xclickcounter.dart (file)
      xclickcounter.html (file)
```

Lib folder contains library which is just copy of ClickCounter component renamed to Comp1. The question is **how should I reference Comp1 to use it inside the newcomposite.html?**. So far I am getting number of error in out folder code which I am not even supposed to change. See exact code below:

Source
**mylib.dart:**

```dart
library mylib;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

part 'comp1.dart';
```

**comp1.dart:**

```dart
part of mylib;

class Comp1 extends WebComponent {
  @observable
  int count = 0;

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

**Comp1.html**

```dart
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-comp1" constructor="Comp1" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div>
          <button on-click="increment()">Click me</button><br />
          <span>(click count: {{count}})</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="comp1.dart"></script>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

**newcomposite.html (where reference should be)**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newcomposite.css">

    <!-- import the comp1-->
    <link rel="import" href="lib/comp1.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>NewComposite</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <div is="x-comp1" id="click_counter" count="{{startingCount}}"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="newcomposite.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try moving your lib referencing your own project as a package as per my answer below? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

It should work better if you move your lib directory up into the root of your project:

```
NewComposite (folder)
   pubspec.lock (file)
   pubspec.yaml (file)
   lib(folder)
      comp1.dart (file)
      comp1.html (file)
      mylib.dart (file)
   web (folder)
      newcomposite.css (file)
      newcomposite.dart (file)
      newcomposite.html (file)
      xclickcounter.dart (file)
      xclickcounter.html (file)
```

Assuming you have named your project as "newcomposite" in the pubspec.yaml, you can then import your component into newcomposite.html by referring to your own project library:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newcomposite.css">

    <!-- import the comp1-->
    <link rel="import" href="package:newcomposite/comp1.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>NewComposite</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <div is="x-comp1" id="click_counter" count="{{startingCount}}"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="newcomposite.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```